# MEGA Api: Dowload a file

Tags: c#, api, mega-api

I try to download a file (an image) from mega. I download the API MegaApiClient from NuGet in Visual Studio 2015 (github project: https://github.com/gpailler/MegaApiClient).
I try to do this:

```
 MegaApiClient mega = new MegaApiClient();
        mega.Login("username", "password");

        const string fileName = "fileName.jpg";
        const string folderName = "FilmImage";

        IEnumerable<INode> nodes = mega.GetNodes();
        List<INode> folders = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();
        INode folder = folders.Where(f => f.Name == folderName).FirstOrDefault();
```

How to get the file from this folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is get a list of all the files and find the one with the required name:

```
IEnumerable<INode> nodes = mega.GetNodes();
List<INode> allFiles = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.File).ToList();
INode myFile = allFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == fileName);
```

You could then download it or do something else with it:

```
DownloadFile(myFile, downloadPath)
```

Comment: Tanks. But is useless get folder and than files? Better: I catch all files in all folders and than linq to search the file? Another question: I want to download save the file, then store the image in the c# Image class. Which is the temp folder for save file?

Comment: In theory, it's better to find a specific folder, and get the list only of its files - not all files in all folders as I've done above. However, I have not used this API and did not find anything in their documentation about how to drill down from a specific folder.
Question 1: yes, you can catch all files in all folders. 
Question 2: you can pass any location on your computer as "downloadPath", e.g. "C://Users//Test//Desktop//sample.jpg". You can then  load it many ways, for example: Image myImg = Image.FromFile("path here");

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<INode> nodes = client.GetNodes();
List<INode> folders = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();
INode myFolder = folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "FolderName");
IEnumerable<INode> folder = client.GetNodes(myFolder);
List<INode> allFiles = folder.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.File).ToList();
INode myFile = allFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "FileName");
mega.DownloadFile(myFile, "DownloadFileDirectory");
```